# SQL Server bulk insert special characters / Unicode from C# generated CSV

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unicode

Scenario:
CSV text file generated from C# to be imported into SQL Server database using BULK INSERT. Some fields contain special characters (aka Unicode).

Problem:
The special characters display correctly in the text file, but are not being saved correctly in the database.

Edit: Example of correct text is "Khālid Muḥammad ʻAlī al-Ḥājj" and incorrect text is "Kha¯lid Muh?ammad ?Ali¯ al-H?a¯jj".

Comment: What is your question here? You say that aren't being saved "correctly", what does that mean? Are they the wrong character, do they appear oddly, are they missing entirely (no character there), something else? What does "not being saved correctly" mean?

Comment: So what was the code you were using when it wasn't working? Yes, you've written an answer here, but it doesn't really show what the problem you initially had was. There's no code to replicate the issue, meaning that future readers won't know if this answer related to them, as they don't know what the code that caused your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I pieced together the answer to this from several sources, so here is the whole thing in one place.

(1) The text file must be marked as a Unicode file.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append: false, encoding: Encoding.Unicode);
```

(2) The database columns must use Unicode data types. For example, NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR. Use one of the data types that starts with "N".

Side note: you can mark string literals in T-SQL as Unicode strings by prefixing them with an N.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Name) VALUES (N'special characters');
```

(3) Specify DATAFILETYPE='widechar' in the BULK INSERT command. (If the file is not marked Unicode, this will throw an error.)

```
BULK INSERT dbo.myTable FROM 'C:\path\fileName.csv' 
WITH (DATAFILETYPE ='widechar', FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR='|', ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

(4) Use database collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.